# Cuál es el error: Desafortunadamente, la aplicación se ha parado

Tags: java, android

He desarrollado una aplicación sencilla en Android Studio para acceder a una web más fácilmente y cuándo la abro me dice que se ha parado.

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.beep.estudiosrdouscehlo.MainActivity">


<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.beep.estudiosrdouscehlo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final WebView web=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(web.canGoBack()){
        web.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebSettings ajustes=web.getSettings();
    ajustes.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
} }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

package="com.example.beep.estudiosrdouscehlo">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Ese "se ha parado" te lo dice en el device/emulador ?  tienes algún log o trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se encuentra aquí al tratar de obtener la referencia del `WebView`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final WebView web=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Define una variable pero la referencia la puedes obtener en `onCreate()` esto para que no obtengas un  `NullPointerException` como error:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final WebView web;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //*** Obten aquí la referencia del WebView:
    web =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings ajustes=web.getSettings();
    ajustes.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, todo solucionado

Comment: Excelente Roger, saludos!